# Why Path.GetFullPath returns the address with extra "bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0"?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a file **on mac** which is at `/Users/Bsh/Desktop/myProgram/myFile.txt` when I use this address instead of `Path.GetFullPath("myFile.txt")` in the C# program, the file is found by the program but when I use `Path.GetFullPath("myFile.txt")` the program does not find the file. To find out what `Path.GetFullPath` returns, I used `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath("myFile.txt"));` and the output was `/Users/Bsh/Desktop/myProgram/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/myFile.txt`.

Why is there an extra part: `bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0`? And how to resolve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of the "current directory" of a program? If not, start by learning about that concept. If yes, can you say a little about what you believe to be true about the current directory?

Comment: What version of dotnet core are you on? Do you have a `csproj` file in your project directory?

Comment: `bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0` ... this is where your code is actually executing from. If you want to define the path to your file.. you have to hard code the full path to your file. If your file exists within your project, you can use this to access the file. `$@"{Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName}\YourFile.txt";`

Comment: @Jawad Thanks a lot, it works and your answer is the best.

Comment: @Jawad's answer is problematic; be aware that, depending on how myFile.txt is included in the project, and on how your application is installed; the file may not be stored at that path, and may even not be installed at all. You have to tell us more information on how you are including files and how you will be deploying your application.

Comment: It can be problemetic if you dont know where your file is at. The path i mentioned was strictly for files located within your project (not as resources or lnks).

Answer (score 1):

The first step you should take when a library method is not working as expected, is **Read The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8)**.

In particular, you should be paying special attention to this part:

> This method uses the current directory and current volume information to fully qualify path. If you specify a file name only in path, `GetFullPath` returns the fully qualified path of the current directory.

The answer to your question seems rather obvious.

Comment: I get that the person posing this question is missing some basic concepts, but that doesn't mean you have to be a jerk about it.